# Scollable element focus on main page scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, focus

I've created an inner scrollable section inside an scrollable page.

I want to scroll it when the page scroll reaches it (takes focus).

Here is an demo (also on codepen)
https://codepen.io/maxjf1/pen/JjGwbmB

Fullscreen for better view

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: coral;
  color: white;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 0;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.image {
  background: url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/493220.jpg');
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-size: 2em;
  background: blueviolet;
  color: white;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque esse assumenda repellat vitae placeat voluptatum nesciunt voluptas quasi, adipisci ex nobis? Voluptate officia tempore minus eos. Odit quibusdam repudiandae eius.
</p>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque esse assumenda repellat vitae placeat voluptatum nesciunt voluptas quasi, adipisci ex nobis? Voluptate officia tempore minus eos. Odit quibusdam repudiandae eius.
</p>

<div class="wrapper" tabindex="1">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eum perferendis, quidem nemo, debitis odio magnam ipsa alias quos provident esse ea neque iusto impedit repellat harum, eos aperiam necessitatibus sapiente?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image"></div>

</div>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque esse assumenda repellat vitae placeat voluptatum nesciunt voluptas quasi, adipisci ex nobis? Voluptate officia tempore minus eos. Odit quibusdam repudiandae eius.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque esse assumenda repellat vitae placeat voluptatum nesciunt voluptas quasi, adipisci ex nobis? Voluptate officia tempore minus eos. Odit quibusdam repudiandae eius.
</p>
```

Comment: What have you tried? It seems it works as you expect in the snippet in Firefox..

Comment: @Kaddath I've tried the pen in firefox and it also doesn't work. it only works if you click or wait the mouse on the scrollable element. If you scroll directly it doesn't scroll.

Comment: For instance, i want it to work like this, but scrolling in the inner element https://codepen.io/maxjf1/pen/WNrLZZv